# Bulk insert fixed width fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do you specify field lengths with the Bulk Insert command?

Example: If I had a table named c:\Temp\TableA.txt and it had:

```
123ABC
456DEF
```

And I had a table such as:

```
use tempdb
CREATE TABLE TABLEA(
Field1 char(3),
Field2 char(3)
)
BULK INSERT TableA FROM 'C:\Temp\TableA.txt'
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

Then how would I specify the lengths for Field1 and Field2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to define a format file

e.g.

```
BULK INSERT TableA FROM 'C:\Temp\TableA.txt'
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\Format.xml')
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

For that to work, though, you need a Format File, obviously.

See here for general info about creating one:

[Creating a Format File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

At a guess, from looking at the [Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189327%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), something like this might do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Field1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="3"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Field2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="3"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks!  I just learned that I get this when trying to use Bulk Insert: Msg 4834, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

Comment: Don't you need brackets around the formatfile bit? WITH ( FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\Format.xml')

Comment: @HeinduPlessis oh yes you're right, edited

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to use a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx) with your [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). Something like:

```
9.0
2
1     SQLCHAR     0     03     ""         1     Field1          ""
2     SQLCHAR     0     03     "\r\n"     2     Field2          ""
```