# How to use metadata or have sql recall column width on a fixed width .txt file import

Tags: sql, metadata

Ill preface this by stating that I have searched and searched and have yet to find my answer.

Long story short, I have a .txt file of around 1.5mm rows and 200 columns. The columns are all set fixed width that I ahve a metadata file for. I get a new file about every 6 months and have been entering the column widths manually. I am trying to figure out a way for sql to recall the widths or how to load the metadata so I can set it to that. The manual process is tedious and time consuming.

It is highly possible that I am just searching the wrong keywords. Any advice would be great but guidance of where I can read and learn about this process would be better(still sort of a beginner here).

thanks

Comment: please specify which DBMS are you using

Comment: Did the response helped you? If so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
BULK INSERT TableA FROM '{inputfilename}'
WITH FORMATFILE = '{xmlformatfile}'
```

look at [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields) for more details