# Inserting datafiles into a SQL Server database (no separators)

Tags: c#, database, search, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I've tried researching this question but most of the answers is for `.csv` files which does not help me a lot.

I have a couple of large `.dat` files containing quite a lot of data (each file around 700MB), and I am trying to develop a software in C# where I will be able to search for a specific string and locate the line where it is (duplicates will occur so a listview / listbox might be a good idea).

Every line follows the exact same data format and the starting index/length of each datatype is well documented.

Example:

> Line 1: ZATIXIZ20SWEDENSTACKOVERFLOWCHROME
>
> Documented like this:
>
> Username : 0-6 
>  Age : 7-8 
>  Country: 9-14 
>  Website :
>   15-27 
>  Browser : 28-33

My guess is that the best approach would be to do some kind of BULK INSERT on the data files into a database and then index it for faster searching later on. I am not quite sure how to do this though, nor what the best approach would be. (It also needs to search through all of the files so maybe it could be a good idea to insert them all into the same table?)

So far I have only tried to read one of the files into memory and then do a simple Regex which of course was not a good idea. Unfortunately I am a bit inexperienced with SQL queries which is why I have not tried a lot yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Insert all data of the same type into a table with indexed columns.

If the properties vary between each file, use multiple tables.

If you want to be able to trace the match back to the original file, use a table with columns:

- Key - Internal key from a sequence
- FileName - So you know where it came from
- Line - The line number
- Username
- Age
- Country
- Website
- Browser

Where FileName, Line is a unique key.

Here is a link to an article on full-text searching on MSSQL as we don't know which RDMS you are using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#queries

From you example, the line 'ZATIXIZ20SWEDENSTACKOVERFLOWCHROME' becomes:

```
| Key | FileName   | Line | Username  | Age | CountryKey | Website         | BrowserKey
    1   'Data1.dat'     1   'ZATIXIZ'    20         46     'STACKOVERFLOW'            4
```

In this example, you'd need two more tables: Countries and Browsers. These are optional, as you could just include the information directly in the main table.

I must stress though, that it really depends on how you wish to query this data. The above structure gives you the opportunity to search for 'all swedish users between 20 and 25)' by performing the following query:

```
select * from TABLENAME where Age < 25 and Age >= 20 and CountryKey = 46
```

In regards to how you import a fixed width file, it depends greatly on your RDMS. If you're using Oracle, you can use [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2ALoader_FAQ). Remember that it does not necessarily have to be a single-stage process. You can load the data into the tables and then look up the keys internally after the initial import.

For MSSQL, here is another answer from the stack: [Bulk insert fixed width fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields)

You can also preprocess it in .NET. Again, it depends on your scenario. If you are piping these into your system at a rate of one 900MB file every 10 minutes, you're looking at some serious optimization of the bulk load process (and some serious hardware). But if you only need to load this file once a month, the .NET approach is absolutely fine, even though it may take a few hours.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Troels Larsen. I will take a look at the article and make sure to add the extra columns you mentioned, I'm not quite sure how I would insert all the lines specifying where the data is located on the line (i.e "website" starting at 15 reaching to 27), would you be able to give an example on that? (I would be able to do it in c# but what I won't be able to do is using only SQL queries) Thanks!

Comment: I have added an example, hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks alot Troels. I didn't know that it was called "fixed width". I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I updated my question. I am using MSSQL.