# Many FIELDTERMINATORs or first two characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to perform BULK INSERT like this:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
BULK INSERT myDepartment FROM 'C:\myDepartment-c-t.txt'
WITH (
  DATAFILETYPE = 'SQLCHAR',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

The strings to be imported are like "/useless" or "/practical". I need it to be transformed to "/u" or "/p" (two first characters).
There are two options to do this:

- select only two first characters
- make FIELDTERMINATOR equal to "s" OR "r"

Is any of these options possible?

Comment: I generally recommend to load the data into a staging table and then to do the type and value transformations in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fixed-width import may be more suitable for this task than using delimiters.

[Bulk insert fixed width fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields)