# Update multiple tables from fixed width file

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to do a bulk import into SQL Server 2005 using a fixed width file that has data to be written to 3 different tables. I am not sure the best way to go about this. I assume the best way would be to import all of the data into a single table and update each of the 3 from the new staging table. I am not sure though how to import the data into the table from the fixed width file.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: [BCP understands fixed width files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields) for the initial insert

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used this method with a format file but I am receiving the following errors:  Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
There are no row terminators (that I can see) in the fixed width file I am trying to import. Any ideas?

Comment: Also,  I am attempting to use an XML format file.