# SQL Script Has to be Changed to Reduce SQL Serverload

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

A couple of years ago it was a script designed to import persons into a temporary table. Now this script takes 10 minutes to load and that causes problems sometimes.

So I decided to check the code for optimizing but I have no clue how I can change it.

The current code looks like this

```
// Getting attributes from the configfile
string filePath = getAppSetting("filepath");
string fileName = getAppSetting("filename");
string fileBP = filePath + fileName;

if (File.Exists(fileBP))
{
    // Truncate Temp-Table
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_person];", connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open,     FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamReader logFileReader = new StreamReader(logFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

while (!logFileReader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = logFileReader.ReadLine();
    strActLine = line;
    string sql = "INSERT INTO temp_person(per_nummer, per_pid, per_name)"
                 + "VALUES(@per_nummer, @per_pid, @per_name)"

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_nummer", isNull(line.Substring(0, 7)));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_pid", isNull(line.Substring(7, 7)));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_name", isNull((line.Substring(14, 20))));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
// Clean up
connection.Close();
logFileReader.Close();
    logFileStream.Close();
}
```

In this code I open for each person a new connection and it makes no sense to do that. Is it possible to change that to a bulk insert or something like that? The file does not have any kind of separators like a ";"

I'm Using
MSSQL 2008 R2, 
.Net 4.0 (higher is currently not possible on this server)

Comment: looks like it is already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using SSIS and a Flat file source? It takes minutes to setup. SSIS uses BULK INSERT which means it can insert  hundreds of rows per second.

Comment: Or you can simply use BULK INSERT directly to insert your fixed-width file, as the linked question shows

Comment: Using SSIS will bring in other dependencies, which the user may not want.

Comment: @RichRousseau the only "dependency" is SQL Server itself. It's part of the product. In fact, simply selecting Task>Import Data will bring up a wizard that in the end generates and executes an SSIS package. Anyway, SSIS is the right tool for ETL jobs

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason, this question should probably be closed as duplicate of eg. the question linked by @Jeremy

Comment: it's not allowed in my case using SSIS.

so if no Fieldtermintor is existing I should use SELECT * FROM temp_person and it sees automaticly how long the string is?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Right.  My point was just that SSIS cannot be used without either running on the SQL Server, or bringing in SSIS related dependencies.  SSIS can be run independently of a full SQL Server install, but it does require some components.  See - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your logFileStream file ("fileName") has all the users you are loading, you are NOT opening a new connection as you think.  It is currently using one connection to TRUNCATE the table, then load all entries from the file fileName.

The only way to make this run any faster would be to use the Bulk Insert SQL Server statement, details of which you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a single connection and there *are* alternatives, like using SSIS or bcp. All viable alternatives use the bulk import mechanism but their flexibility varies

Comment: He commented that he was using multiple connections--connecting with each insert, which is not true per the code he posted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.100).aspx) class? It provides several different ways to bulk-copy data from .NET code into SQL Server. Here's an example using a `DataTable` to buffer the records:

```
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    TruncateTempTable(connection);
    DataTable newRecs = new DataTable();
    newRecs.Columns.Add("per_nummer", typeof (string));
    newRecs.Columns.Add("per_pid", typeof(string));
    newRecs.Columns.Add("per_name", typeof(string));
    using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        while (tr.Peek() > 0)
        {
            string theLine = tr.ReadLine();
            DataRow newRow = newRecs.NewRow();
            newRow["per_nummer"] = theLine.Substring(0, 7);
            newRow["per_pid"] = theLine.Substring(7, 7);
            newRow["per_name"] = theLine.Substring(14, 20);
            newRecs.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newRecs);
}
```

Much more detail is available at the MSDN link above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
BULK INSERT Reports FROM  @ReportFile WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

if file data like

```
M1009|20130502|E400969|ARACIL ALONDRA A|2013050220131202201404022014040220140408
M1009|20130502|N1000533|BARRY PATRICIA| 2013050220131202201404022014040220140408
M1009|20130502|N1001263|GRAYSON JOSEPH| 2013050220131202201404022014040220140408
M1009|20130502|N1026710|GANZI LOUIS R.| 2013050220131202201404022014040220140408
```

this should works with t-sql

Comment: i do nat have a FIELDTERMINATOR in the file. its like your first roe without the "|"