# sql bulkinsert using space as separator

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a question and I can't figure it if it's even possible. 
I have a .txt file that i want to bulkinsert to Sql Server and it looks like this :

```
40774529655                     Active      2015-12-25 06:12:42   0        Open                   1042=1.335000
40774537805                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774540998                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774597906                     Active      2015-12-28 15:41:04   0        Open                   1042=0.000000
40774591677                     Active      2015-12-28 15:50:57   0        Open                   1042=0.000000
40774584830                     Active      2015-12-28 11:41:48   0        Open                   1042=0.000000
40772105548                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774511763                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774511764                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774511766                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774511768                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774511769                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
40774511770                     Idle                              0        Open                   1042=2.000000
```

Separator is "space". Is it possible to bulk insert a file like this (using space as separator) or I need somehow to format this file in csv ?

Comment: I'd say it's not that you have space as a separator, but rather that you want to import a **fixed width** file. Have a look at eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields or google around 'fixed width bcp import'

Comment: Thanks for answer, after i tried all methods , the best way is to just strip the spaces with a batch script i will provide short and just bulk insert