# How to parse string into multiple tables in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, openrowset

I have a text file that was created by dumping 8 SQL tables into it. Now I need to import this data back into SQL Server.

Using BULK insert I was able to load data into one table with single column `'FileData'`.

```
DECLARE @FileTable TABLE (FileData NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @FileTable
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK N'C:\My\Path\Name\FileName.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents

SELECT * FROM @FileTable
```

So now I have this huge string that I need to organize into different tables.

For example this part of string corresponds to the below table :

```
FileData
00001                 00000009716496000000000331001700000115200000000000
```

Table:

[image]

It also seems like all fields have a set length and I can get that length.

I can see doing something like this:

```
select SUBSTRING('00001                 00000009716496000000000331001700000115200000000000   ', 1,5) as RecordKey
select SUBSTRING('00001                 00000009716496000000000331001700000115200000000000   ', 6,17) as Filler
select SUBSTRING('00001                 00000009716496000000000331001700000115200000000000   ', 23,16) as BundleAnnualPremium
```

[image]

But is any faster and better way to load this data into different tables?

Comment: `insert into FirstOfEightTables ( C1, C2, ... ) select Substring( FileData, 1, 42 ), Cast( Substring( FileData, 43, 69 ) as SuitableType ), ... from @FileTable; insert into SecondOfEightTables ,,,;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just [bulk insert with a format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825901/bulk-insert-fixed-width-fields) right from the start. But since the data is already loaded into a big table, if you'd rather use pure TSQL, you can pull elements out of a string using [`left()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [`right()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and [`substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).